# TreeView with multiple types

Tags: wpf, treeview

I would like to build a treeview like this:

```
People
Person 1
    Relatives
        Relative 1
        Relative 2
    Mom
    Dad
    Pets
        Pet 1
        Pet 2
```

The problem is that a person has 2 lists (Relatives and Pets) and two Single Items (Mom and Dad).  I'm pretty familiar with HierarchicalDataTemplates but I haven't figured out a way to do this- there are lots of examples out there but none seem to mix types like this.

To make things even more interesting, there may be People without a Mom or a Dad (sad but true).  The list would need to reflect this.

The data Im using originates from the data base using entity framework, so my list of people already has the correct structure- and I would prefer NOT to have all my objects derive from some common composite object (also in many of the examples) where everyone has a 'Name' and 'Children'.  I would like to use the natural properties of each object, like MomsFirstName, PersonsName in the bindings of my datatemplates as well.

Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like your Person Class and the other entities associated with it are in your Model layer. While it accurately models the data from your data-base it does not necessarily make it easy to prepare the data for a View. I suggest translating your Model into a ViewModel with a full hierarchy using interfaces and/or base classes.

Comment: @EtherDragon Yup.  If data needs preparation, then I would certainly use a VM.  But if it doesn't then I tend to avoid VMs for those types.  But in this case, either way the problem is the same for the treeview.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you, but you can supply your own template selector, to pick a different template per type; They will all be encapsulated by the ItemsPanelTemplate object you choose, but it will allow you to have very different controls for any type you specify. This is my use case, but I imagine you could apply the same idea to the TreeView

```
 <ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="templateFoo">
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="templateBar">
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="templateJoe">
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:MyTemplateSelector></local:MyTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                Value="{Binding Row}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

And this somewhere

```
public class MyTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element == null || item == null)
            return null;

        if(item is Foo)
        {
            return element.FindResource("templateFoo") as DataTemplate;
        }

        if (item is Bar)
        {
            return element.FindResource("templateBar") as DataTemplate;
        }

        if (item is Joe)
        {
            return element.FindResource("templateJeo") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace this with type-based data templating using the [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) property...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector?